# ChildOf constraint not updating transforms properly on influence change

Tags: rigging, constraints, auto-rig-pro

I've noticed a very weird problem regarding the transform update of ChildOf when I change it's influence.
I have a specific setup for an arm that looks like this:

```
root
    hand_ik
        socket
            ChildOf(hand_fk)
    hand_fk
```

I am running an IK/FK switch on them, that also triggers a ChildOf constraint for the socket to change to hand_fk when the switch is on 1. I've noticed that sometimes the constraint do not update the transform and I have to click both Set Inverse and Clear Inverse to make it pop in the right place. When I do that, everything works fine. Is there a way to make it do that automatically so animators won't need to do that whenever they change the switch?

As for technical information: the rig is created on AutoRig Pro, on blender 3.6.5 LTS, sadly the socket has to be parented on hand_ik because I can't touch the skeleton hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The proper setup looks like this:

```
root
    hand_ik   
    hand_fk
    socket
            ChildOf(hand_fk)
            ChildOf(hand_ik)
```

Then you switch ik/fk one childof should be off, second - on.

But in the rig there is a bone that already do this - this is a deform bone for skinning that can be in a hidden bone layer.

```
root
    hand_ik   
    hand_fk
    ...
    DEF-hand
         ChildOf(hand_fk)
         ChildOf(hand_ik)
          socket
```

Knowing that, you can parent to that DEF bone and don't mess up this constraints.

Comment: I know that properly socket should be done on skeleton (and not on a controller), but as I've added at the end - I can't touch the skeleton hierarchy (as it's a working in-engine rig) - that's why I am searching for hack solutions that won't kill this characters pipeline. I've done it the way you proposed before (as thats clearly the easiest way) as I believed ARP wont export these controllers as bones - but sadly it does and it changes whole hierarchy.

Comment: Well, try using two constraints than. Moving parent bone will change transform of child, that requires updating inverse transform, so two constraints will solve the issue

Comment: If I'll do a ChildOf for the hand_ik won't it work as a double transform? (As it's the same in hierarchy). I wanted to just add 
```bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse()
bpy.ops.constraint.childof_clear_inverse()```
to the Snap IK-FK button and see if it'll fix, but ill try the double constraint.

Comment: And as I've tested - it makes no difference, because the socket is a child of hand_ik anyway - still I have to invoke ```bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse()``` to snap it.